# Using existing ajax data that is loaded into page

Tags: ajax, javascript

Hey guys thanks in advance,
is there a `js` function that I can use on an existing data that was generated by a plugin with an `ajax` request ? Iv checked it is loaded with the network tab.
but I'm not sure how can access it ?

Comment: There's no generic answer. It depends entirely on the plugin, and what the plugin does with that data. I suggest asking the plugin developer. 3rd-party plugins are off-topic here.

Comment: Unless the plugin stored it somewhere, no, if it did then you'd need to refer to that plugins docs to find out what it did and how it did it. Otherwise no there's no generic WP method

Comment: thanks for the quick reply's and the mention regarding the 3rd party plugins.
so basically unless I make a new ajax request or using methods from the plugin I cant access it.